# Inconsistancy of raw moments between skimage and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I am trying to replace opencv functions with a more pythonic approach by using similar functions in `numpy` and `skimage`. The raw moments are not the same but the centroids are similar. I was wondering if there are any implementation differences regarding moment computation between `skimage` and `cv2`?

```py
from skimage import measure

contour = measure.find_countour(img)
m = cv2.moments(contour.astype(np.float32)) # only works with CV_32F
print(m["m00"], m["m10"] / m["m00"], m["m01"] / m["m00"])
```

results from `cv2`:

```
9231.5 781.3878567946704 567.7414649118056
```

However if I use skimage

```py
...
m = measure.moments_coords(contour)
print(m[0, 0], m[1, 0] / m[0, 0], m[0, 1] / m[0, 0])
```

results for `skimage`:

```
513.0 781.7534113060428 567.4697855750487
```

from the opencv documentation, `cv2.contourArea` should yield the same result as raw moment `m["m00"]` (which I also verified to be true when the data type is `np.float32`). And since there is no similar function in skimage I had to use `m[0, 0]` but I am confused as to why it doesn't match the one in cv2.

**Edit**

Here is the image[image: basic square]

Full code for preprocessing:

```py
import cv2
import pathlib
import numpy as np
from skimage import measure

filepath = pathlib.Path("/path/to/test/image.png")
print(filepath)

img = cv2.imread(str(filepath))

# preprocessing steps
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, bi = cv2.threshold(inv, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# cv_contours, _ = cv2.findContours(bi, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# print(cv_contours[0], np.squeeze(cv_contours[0], 1))
sk_contour = measure.find_contours(bi)[0]
cv_contour = np.expand_dims(sk_contour.astype(np.int32), 1)

cv_m = cv2.moments(cv_contour)
print(cv_m["m00"], cv_m["m10"] / cv_m["m00"], cv_m["m01"] / cv_m["m00"])

sk_m = measure.moments_coords(sk_contour.astype(np.int32))
print(sk_m[0, 0], sk_m[1, 0] / sk_m[0, 0], sk_m[0, 1] / sk_m[0, 0])
```

results:

```
14341364.5 3022.5001979646586 3022.5001979646586
15149.0 3022.8749752458907 3022.874909234933
```

Comment: opencv is known to be inaccurate due to its notion of a contour, which differs from the notion of a polygon, and how `cv.moments()` treats those inputs as polygons, not contours.

Comment: `m00` should not differ by an order of magnitude. [mre] required.

Comment: We need to see how you processed the image before getting the moments. Did you threshold differently or at all?  Are your input images grayscale or color. Did you convert color images to grayscale before thresholding? If so are the channel orders the same?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have added a minimal reproducible example with a test image. As shown in the example, the centroid is still the same but `m00` is still not the same. Interestingly, if my contours are of type `np.float32` it gives me slightly more error (centroid will be `3023, 3022`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your calling `moments_coords()`.

It does ***not*** take a contour. It literally takes the set of ***all*** points in the connected component.

This is their example, from the docs.
They build up a list of all points in a rectangle, not just the perimeter.

```
>>> coords = np.array([[row, col]
...                    for row in range(13, 17)
...                    for col in range(14, 18)], dtype=np.float64)
>>> M = moments_coords(coords)
>>> centroid = (M[1, 0] / M[0, 0], M[0, 1] / M[0, 0])
>>> centroid
(14.5, 15.5)
```

https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.moments_coords

With a proper [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you could make a lot more sense of the resulting values and come up with hypotheses.

```
bi = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
(x,y,w,h) = 20, 20, 50, 50
img[y:y+h, x:x+w] = 255
```

That gives you a 50 by 50 box, area 2500, perimeter 200, sum 2500*255 = 637500.

From any further analysis, you'll get various results. The `measure.moments_coords(sk_contour)` returns 201 for `m00` then. That is suspicious.

Comment: so there is no similar function that calculates the "contour moment" like in opencv then?

Comment: why do you _require_ this calculation on a *contour*? you have the source image, you can calculate moments directly on that, ***OR*** label its components first, then use `skimage.measure.regionprops()`